# How is Goldy related to the lady?

Tags: logic

The question in concern that I'm trying to solve:

> Introducing a lady in party Goldy told her friend, “She is sister-in-law of my only brother who is
> father of Ganesh who is grandson of Navya’s husband who is my father who have only two children.”
> How is Ganesh related to that lady?

If we think of it this way from the lady's point of view, Goldy is the lady's sister's husband's brother. Which makes Goldy the lady's brother-in-law's brother. However, in the answer key, it is mentioned that Goldy is the lady's nephew. Can someone clear the confusion here?

I have included the solution they have used below.
[image: This is the official solution provided.]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with philosophy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any of these people, but according to pronouns Goldy should be female

> Introducing a lady in party Goldy told **her** friend

Which makes Goldy the lady's brother-in-laws sister or less confusing the lady's sister-in-law. So far so good. Your problem is that this wasn't the question. The question is:

> How is **Ganesh** related to that lady?

And Ganesh is the child of the lady's brother-in-law, so as:

> In the lineal kinship system used in the English-speaking world, a niece or nephew is a child of an individual's sibling or sibling-in-law.

Ganesh would be the lady's [nephew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niece_and_nephew) given that he is Navya’s husband's grandson.